# How can I extract the colors from a bitmap using the magick R package?

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the colors from an image using the `magick` package.  I believe the colors can be obtained by using the `image_data()` function, but I don't know enough about bitmap objects to figure out how.

```r
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.12.3
#> Enabled features: cairo, freetype, fftw, ghostscript, heic, lcms, pango, raw, rsvg, webp
#> Disabled features: fontconfig, x11

img <- image_read('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')
image_data(img)
#> 4 channel 272x92 bitmap array: 'bitmap' raw [1:4, 1:272, 1:92] 00 00 00 00 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/01/extracting-colours-from-your-images-with-image-quantization/

Comment: Try using `image_raster()` instead of `image_data()`, it returns a three-column data frame with pixel *x* and *y* coordinates and color.

Comment: @RobertHacken I tried ``ìmage_raster(img)``` , but get a wierd error: ```Error: Image pointer is dead. You cannot save or cache image objects between R sessions.```. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Andy Not really..

Comment: @RobertHacken ahh too bad. I really wanted to solve the problem for Joshbrows. Maybe my problem is an OS problem and would be fine on PC